# One-time payments with React Native/Stripe/Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

i have started to implement the payment process using Firebase-Stripe extension. I have also set up a custom webhook to add collections for customers, manage products etc. in the firestore database. But now i have a couple of conceptual problems and questions:

1. Is it possible to make browser pop-up from an app with all the payment process being handled by stripe(payment screen layout, payment options etc.) and then redirecting back to the app after the payment is finished? If so, is it an effective way to go?
2. If i have tickets with additional information and price, can i generate programmatically a stripe product in the products collection without creating it in the stripe dashboard?
3. Can you give me a starting point to implement points 1-2? I was trying to search for any references to do that, but i couldn’t find any relevant ones.

At least some help would be highly appreciated ❤️

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to make browser pop-up from an app with all the payment process being handled by stripe(payment screen layout, payment options etc.) and then redirecting back to the app after the payment is finished? If so, is it an effective way to go?

You would need to display a webview in your mobile app that then redirects to Stripe Checkout, which is a pre built payment page for your customers to enter their card info into.

Alternatively, there is a Stripe built ReactNative integration that allows you to collect payments natively in your mobile app, using the [PaymentSheet component](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native).

> If i have tickets with additional information and price, can i generate programmatically a stripe product in the products collection without creating it in the stripe dashboard?

Using either a backend server or adding functionality to your Firebase extension, [you can programmatically create Products](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create) using your secret API key.

Comment: So, if i understood correctly, following first link you provided i can instantly move on to the client-side setup step since i already have firebase-stripe extension(server-side setup step) configured?

Comment: you can _if_ that Firebase extension creates CheckoutSessions for you, which is what you would use to redirect to Checkout client-side